# how to make parsing of the txt file and divided into three columns

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to read the file *.txt and upload it to a grid in a C# WPF app.
I broke the string by string and then do not know how to check

The data must be divided into three columns: date, class and description

```
public class DataTextFile
{
    public string TimeData { get; set; }
    public string Clasa { get; set; }
    public DateTime Discription { get; set; }
}

public class ReadFromFile
{
    public static List<DataTextFile> ReaList(string path)
    {
        var dataList = new List<DataTextFile>();
        foreach (var file in File.ReadAllLines(path))
        {
            var columns = file.Split(' ');
            //var data = columns[0] + columns[1];

            dataList.Add(new DataTextFile
            {
                TimeData = columns[0],
                Clasa = columns[1],
                Discription = columns[2]
            });
        }
        return dataList;
    } 
}
```

---

input text file

```
2015-08-03 13:29:08,377 ModuleManager
Entering PrepareModules
2015-08-03 13:29:08,378 ModuleManager
Entering LoadModules
2015-08-03 13:29:08,378 ModuleManager
LoadModules, _modulesDirectory: C:\Workspace\esuite\UI.Desktop\Larix.Esuite.Desktop\bin\Debug\
2015-08-03 13:29:12,438 ModuleManager
Entering SelfInitialize
```

Comment: What is the question? At the first look, your code is OK, at least, it will parse file's content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Discription` property is a DateTime, and date is separated from time by space in your file. Also your indexes seem messed up. Check what you're getting in `columns` under debug. Add line-by-line error handling. Parse your `DateTime` property like that:

```
 //...
 Discription = DateTime.Parse(columns[0]+" "+columns[1])
 //...
```